# Conditional statements with user input

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a textbot project, where if I input some text in a textbox, the bot spits out something in the console, fairly simple. However, I've run into a problem that I am very frustrated over, and haven't managed to solve. There's probably a simple solution to this, but I can't find it.

What I want to do, is having the textbox accept a command that consists of the user input + a variable that the user inputs. Something like this:

```
case "input " + condition {
  //do something with condition
}
```

My question is how do I make the textbox differ between the input and the condition? I hope this question isn't way too hard to understand, but I don't know how else to explain it :P

Edit:
Example:

Textbox input:

```
"!locate p.actionValue"
```

Then depending on what actionvalue the person inputs, this should return something like:

```
if (actionvalue = 32) {
  //do something if actionvalue is 32
}
```

But how do i differ between the command and condition?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Denieru : Your problem is not clear. Clarify more

Comment: It would probably help if you showed some examples of inputs and conditions.

Comment: Is there a specific pattern the inputs follow? I.e. will it always be `<command> <variable>` or can it be `<command> <variable> arbitrary text`? The former is simple, the latter requires some form of annotation for the variable.

Comment: The former will be fine for this project, I've added an example to my main post, hopefully that clears it up a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to match the input and get the condition:

```
var match;
if (match = input.match(/^!locate (.*)/)) {
    var condition = match[1];
    // do something with condition
}
```

You can get more general:

```
var match = input.match(/^!(\S+)\s+(.*)/);
if (match) {
    var command = match[1];
    var arg = match[2];
    switch (command) {
        case 'locate':
            ...
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the input.match in line 1 of your code? I've never seen those symbols used like that in Javascript, and I'm really confused as to do with them.

Comment: Learn about regular expressions at regular-expression.info.

Comment: So what I do is first search for a match with "!<word>" and then search for a match with a number? And store these in an array?

Comment: When the pattern matches, it returns an array containing the parts of the input that are matched by the parts of the pattern in `( )`. So `match[1]` contains the part that matched `(\S+)`, and `match[2]` contains the part that matched `(.*)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your text by "input " and then you will get the command

```
// array separated by 'input '
var command = textbox.split('input ');
// here you got your command: command[0]
```

of course you'll need to validate that it actually has `'input '`, and what happens in cases like `'input input '`